# Problem with Belkin wifi router. SIgnal strength at 30 % and noise 11 % at 3 meters

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Belkin router. I don't know the exact model, can't find it anywhere, it just says "Belkin VoIP 802.11g gateway". It's pretty big (ipad size) and tall (4 cm) and has an external antenna. The problem I face is that the signal strength is insanely low. I checked with iStumbler and it reports signal strength between 30 and 40 % and noise at 11 % constant. The channel is 1, and other routers around have either 6 or 11.

I cannot pinpoint the reason of the problem. It's not my laptop, another laptop has exactly the same report. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: The problem is that it's made by Belkin. My suggestion would be to purchase a different brand.

Comment: Loose antenna wire, internally?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you have beside the router or between the router an the laptop like TV, speakers or any magnetic field generators and remove them (or move the router).
You can also test with another router just to see if the other router is working well and if it is the place that is bad.